# Is this Use Case correct?

Tags: uml, modeling, use-case, requirements, use-case-diagram

Its my first time making a use case and this is for my coursework.
I had to follow the case study below.

> **Case Study 8:** Warehouse Control System (WCS)
>   A warehouse distributes health food and related products. Customers order a particular
>   product and quantity from the warehouse. The Warehouse Control System WCS saves the
>   order and provides to the customer the order number. The WCS generates a pick list and
>   shopping label, which tells the order-picker person how many of each item to pick to fulfil
>   the order. The order-picker picks the items, places them in the box, and places the shipping
>   label on it. The order-picker then uses the WCS to specify whether the order is ready or
>   not. Then the manager sends the order number, address, and the payment data to the
>   shipping company. At the end of the day, the shipping company arrives to pick up all the
>   orders. The inventory of the product in stock is carried out by the staff, but in others, it is
>   outsourced to an external company. Each staff has a specific function which is either to
>   raise an order or check the re-order level of the products in stock.
>   The company wants to create a computer system that allows employees and external
>   companies to access the application system on desktop. Model, design and implement a
>   GUI client that can access the database using Visual Studio or any other software
>   development package. The database must be designed from the class model and the entity
>   data model using MS Access or Oracle database.

I'm not sure:  should the Warehouse Control System (WCS) be an actor ? If not how to make the use case without it?

Here the use case I made:

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

The WCS is the system under consideration (the blue boundary).

Some observations:

- Use verb-subject(-object) to name use cases
- `Order ready` and the like are no use cases
- Try to not start  functional decomposition (like it seems you did with that `Order ready`

I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases as usual.